# Is it safe to use google service account json file in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, security, google-api

i have built a JS website and it requires some google APIs to be used. For that i use Google Service account. As this is a simple JS, i include my json file like this:

```js
var serviceAccountID = 'xxx@xxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
var calendarID = 'xxx@group.calendar.google.com'

// Establishing connection with Google
loadKey = new XMLHttpRequest();
loadKey.open('GET', 'js/valued-host-218919-xxx.json', false);
loadKey.onreadystatechange = function() {
    jsonFile = JSON.parse(loadKey.response);
}
loadKey.send();
```

Which means, that if i would be that "bad guy", nothing pretends me just copy-pasting json key + account id, and write a script that will access the information.

**Is my statement correct and if so, how should i organise this connection process keeping in mind, that this is a JS based website?**

Is it really so easy to hack a js built website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Addressing your question**

> Is it really so easy to hack a js built website?

I'm afraid that the reply to this is a pretty big **YES**, and to the surprise of many is not that much harder to hack a mobile app, that much developers suppose to not be that easy once the code is compiled into a binary.

So a JS site is just plain code in the browser and you only need to hit F12 to see  it.

But you can make it harder by obfuscating the javascript:

Plain javascript:

```
// Paste your JavaScript code here
function hi() {
    console.log("Hello World!");
 }
 hi();
```

Obfuscated Javascript:

```
var _0x2bc2=['log'];(function(_0x4559ba,_0x43fc2e){var _0x58be47=function(_0x54a5cb){while(--_0x54a5cb){_0x4559ba['push'](_0x4559ba['shift']());}};_0x58be47(++_0x43fc2e);}(_0x2bc2,0xd5));var _0x2916=function(_0x3a4400,_0xb0a1a2){_0x3a4400=_0x3a4400-0x0;var _0x3d6730=_0x2bc2[_0x3a4400];return _0x3d6730;};function hi(){console[_0x2916('0x0')]('Hello\x20World!');}hi();
```

Source: https://obfuscator.io/

You can also use the OWASP Zed Attack Proxy(ZAP) project to help you on evaluating the security of your web app.

[ZAP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project):

> The OWASP Zed Attack Proxy (ZAP) is one of the world’s most popular free security tools and is actively maintained by hundreds of international volunteers*. It can help you automatically find security vulnerabilities in your web applications while you are developing and testing your applications. Its also a great tool for experienced pentesters to use for manual security testing.

**Now let's address your statement/question**

> Is my statement correct and if so, how should i organise this connection process keeping in mind, that this is a JS based website?

Unfortunately in the client side you cannot handle access to third part services in a safe way, thus the best solution for you is to delegate any access to third part services into an API server. This approach let's you have control over who is accessing this services and in the back-end you are able to safely store all secrets needed to access any third part service.

Now you need to deal with controlling who accesses this API and I can tell you in advance that is not an easy task and that no absolute solution exists to protect an API serving an web app.

The most common way to secure an API is to use an `api-key` but that is easily bypassed as you can see in [this series](https://blog.approov.io/tag/a-series-mobile-api-security) of articles about Mobile Api Security Techniques. While the articles are in the context of an API for a mobile app, the majority of the techniques described here are also valid for a web app. This articles will let you know how api-keys, oauth access tokens, hmac, certificate pinning can be used to protect the API and how they can be bypassed.

In the context of an API serving only a web app I recommend, in a first stage, to use the Google reCaptcha V3 solution and afterwards if is deemed insufficient to protect you API from being abused you can start thinking in implementing a User Behaviour Analytics solution, also known as UBA.

[Gogole reCaptcha V3](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3.html):

> reCAPTCHA is a free service that protects your website from spam and abuse. reCAPTCHA uses an advanced risk analysis engine and adaptive challenges to keep automated software from engaging in abusive activities on your site. It does this while letting your valid users pass through with ease.

[UBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_behavior_analytics) on wikipedia:

> User behavior analytics (UBA) as defined by Gartner is a cybersecurity process about detection of insider threats, targeted attacks, and financial fraud. UBA solutions look at patterns of human behavior, and then apply algorithms and statistical analysis to detect meaningful anomalies from those patterns—anomalies that indicate potential threats. Instead of tracking devices or security events, UBA tracks a system's users. Big data platforms like Apache Hadoop are increasing UBA functionality by allowing them to analyze petabytes worth of data to detect insider threats and advanced persistent threats.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and help! Yet another day i am thinking about how to protect the web-app, and yes, looks like the more tricky you are in hiding ongoing processes in the code, the better "security" is. With code obfuscation it is really a possible solution. As for the private key, is there any way i can encode/decode or smth to hide this **"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n** ... **-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n**?

Comment: We are here to help each others... Please do not attempt to handle secrets at all in the client side. Even when using obfuscation is not hard to get hands on your secrets. You rally need to go with a back-end solution to access any third part services.

Comment: Understood. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

SQL Inject could bypass the API system, considering the simplicity of it and all, but other than that you should be good.

Comment: What i am trying to say, i that anyone can just create a program using the same credentials and they will have an access to the information. Google will never identify who is who. Even if i point that "you can trust only this domain", i can use the same credentials from Console and the request will be successfully sent. It's just a matter of understanding the initial code, how it works, and you are good to go...